# Getting cross domain error in ajax request when I return ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a cross-domain ajax call.

I am getting problems in code below.

I get cross domain error if I use `this.opts.dataURL` in url. But when I use value of url it works fine. However both values are same.

```
getData: function(){
    //var dataPath='http://siteurl.com/lastminuteflight';
    var dataPath=this.opts.dataURL;
    alert(dataPath)
    if(this.opts.data){
        return $.Deferred().resolve(this.opts.data);
    } else {
        return $.ajax({
            url: dataPath,
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'GET',
            cache:false,
            async: false
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is `this.opts` ?

Comment: *"I get cross domain error if i use "this.opts.dataURL" in url. but when i use value of url it works fine. However both values are same."* Then that isn't what's happening, it's observational error. (Happens to us all occasionally.)

Comment: Then what's exactly happening in this code?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the values you are trying to use and thin it's failing on.

Comment: My problem solved by adding two extra line.  var dataPath=this.opts.dataURL.split('http');
  dataPath='http'+dataPath[1];  But i don't understand why did this work. Could please someone explain me why did this work? This will help me learning java script concepts.

Comment: if you referring to the same url then you can use relative path instead of the absolute path.